# Application error after deploying to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongoose, mern

I've checked Procfile, package.json. Nothing seems to solve the problem. 
My code for mongoose connection:

```js
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("DB connected");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(`DB connection error: ${err.message}`);
  });
```

[after heroku logs --tail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa9wA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I solved the issue by changing networking access to 'ALLOW ACCESS FROM ANYWHERE' on MongoDB.